# How is Nancy able to attend a private preparatory school?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-craft

In [*The Craft*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115963/), four girls come together at a Catholic preparatory school.  Bonnie, Sarah, Rochelle and Nancy all attend this prep school together.

Bonnie, Sarah and Rochelle are all shown to live in suburban type homes and their families appear to be middle to upper class.  Nancy lives in a single wide mobile home with her mother and stepfather. Nancy's room is even shown to have a large leak in the ceiling and her mother is shown complaining about not being able to pay an electric bill at one point.

From what I understand, preparatory schools are very expensive and/or exclusive.

**How could Nancy's family afford to send her to a private Catholic prep school?  Is this ever discussed in the film?**

Answer (score 1):

To my recollection it's never discussed in the film, however it's not in common for this sort of school to offer scholarships which would allow someone to attend who otherwise couldn't afford it, I would assume that is what happened here.

Again while not explicitly mentioned someone like Nancy's economic status would be well known at the school and would potentially be a factor in her being ostracised and bullied.